# data modules belongs to user MEANJS

Tags: meanjs

Im really new to MEANJS and after some days of google research i can't find a good way and a good tutorial to learn how to make a kind of articles module (like the one in MEANJS starter) belongs to a user.

At now my crud module work well but all the data is displayed for all users. I just want that the user can add article (here this is have an another name but anyway) and only this user can see this article.

I find your question here and you look like to have achieve a kind of what i'm trying. So if you have any tips or any ressources to help me, i'm up ! Of course i have read the mongoose docs part about population and i'm sure this is it, but alone this is hard. I've already tried to link my users module and article module but don't work.

Thanks for your time man, and have a happy coding day :)
Greettings from Paris.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but as I understand you just want to allow users create some entities (articles/posts/ etc.), so each user may see own (and only own) entities. If yes, you can just create Schemas like User and Article. In User model you need to add something like 'articles' field and there you will store articles of this user. 
`articles: [articleSchema]`
for array or 
`article: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article'}`
for single objects.

Comment: Ty Roman but i need to all my users have many article. I understand i can also define my article schema.object.id in an array and access it by the user scheme but i've try first to just enter an user id in my article scheme and list it by user._id == req.user. So now i'm wondering what is the best practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check mongodb entry for articles it already holds the user ObjectId that created the article:

```
> db.articles.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c7751dbafe1a306b6ce54d"), "user" : ObjectId("55c774f9bafe1a306b6ce54c"), "content" : "My latest test. another info", "title" : "Test", "created" : ISODate("2015-08-09T15:43:25.467Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55c7c2edd4bc5f277b775ba9"), "user" : ObjectId("55c774f9bafe1a306b6ce54c"), "content" : "ATESTE", "title" : "TESTE", "created" : ISODate("2015-08-09T21:15:25.762Z"), "__v" : 0 }
>
```

The reason that all articles are loaded when you click "List Articles" menu entry is because the list implementation for articles in articles.server.controller.js does not restrict the find to load only the logged user articles, the default implementation loads all articles from mongodb:

```
/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};
```

I've never tried that but I believe the easiest way to do what you want would be to change that call to have a criteria and load only the articles from the logged in user, something like:

```
/**
 * List of Articles
 */
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  Article.find({user: req.user}).sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function (err, articles) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.json(articles);
    }
  });
};
```

This, or something like this(I didn't test it) should now bring only the logged in user created articles. Check details of mongoose query [here.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i need. I've try it for you and i can confirm this work. Just for everyone, i just change `Article.find({user: req.user}) ...` to `Article.find({'user': req.user}) ... `. user need singlequote because we refer to a schema object. Anyway thanks for your time Marcos and now i'm on the right way to continue my coding life in MEANJS. Thanks again and greetings.